# How to get a string array in SQL subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking for a SQL query that returns multiple data from different table.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT 
    product.*,
    (SELECT category_name FROM category 
     WHERE product.category_id = category_id) AS category_name
FROM 
    product_table AS product
WHERE 
    product.id = 17
```

This request will work perfectly BUT I need this second subquery:

```
(SELECT category_name FROM category 
 WHERE product.category_id = category_id) AS category_name
```

to return the `category_table` with all columns converted into an string array, so I can explode(',', $category_name) in PHP.

So in other words I'm trying to retrieve a table inside another table which is not possible with SQL. I want to convert the row in the `category_table` into a string array, and then convert it back to a real array in PHP.

Expected result:

```
ProductObject {
id => 1,
name => "Product Name",
category => "[id, category_name, category_description]" # It also be a json
}
```

Expected solution type:

```
(SELECT TO_STRING_ARRAY(*) FROM category 
 WHERE product.category_id = category_id) AS category_table
```

Where TO_ARRAY (which doesn't exist) is a SQL function that will convert the row into a string array.

Also this could be a very useful solution cause we can with this get tables inside tables (nested tables) in only one SQL query.

Comment: Lookup `GROUP_CONCAT()`. If you need to nest a table, then I usually do it, by converting the table to XML.

Comment: i'm tempted to write this now (but doesnt work)

`
SELECT 
product.*,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(*) FROM category WHERE product.category_id = category.id) AS category_name
FROM product_table AS product
WHERE product.id = 17
`

If there is a way to auto concatenate all collumns, it would be just great.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` is for a single field (or fields that are concatenated first with `CONCAT`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AS A PARTIAL SOLUTION THAT WORKS GREAT THO**
but could be improved to automatically get each columns names as key

Thanks to @progu i've done some search with JSON_ARRAY and found JSON_OBJECT that fits better to my needs.

Partial solution:

```
SELECT 
 p.*, 
 (SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
     "id", category.id,
     "name", category.name,
     "description", category.description
 ) FROM category WHERE p.category_id = category.id ) AS _category,
FROM product_table p
WHERE p.id = 17
```

JSON_OBJECT works well in my case because i needed the 'key' too.
JSON_ARRAY can work in some case but i'm using function to build Object in PHP from a json string (keys are important for the right object property recognition).

So with JSON_OBJECT i can symply do a json_decode and i have an object.

---

**Is there a way to get each columns names automatically ?**

So i wouldn't need to type by hand all the time this:

```
JSON_OBJECT(
    THIS => "id", 
        category.id,
    THIS => "name", 
        category.name,
    THIS => "description", 
        category.description
)
```

As JSON_OBJECT('key_1', 'value_of_key_1', 'key_2', 'value_of_key_2') works that way.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT` + separator, but there will be problem if your column values contain the separator

```
SELECT a.*, CONCAT(b.category_id, ',', b.category_name, ',', b.category_description) AS cat_info
FROM product_table a 
LEFT JOIN category b ON a.category_id = b.category_id
WHERE a.id = 17
```

Or use [`JSON_ARRAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array)

```
SELECT a.*, JSON_ARRAY(b.category_id, b.category_name, b.category_description) AS cat_info
FROM product_table a 
LEFT JOIN category b ON a.category_id = b.category_id
WHERE a.id = 17
```

Comment: This answer helped me to find a good workaround ! JSON_OBJECT('id', 17, 'name', category.name). I'll post an answer to myself as partial solution